# How to map entity and component

Tags: hibernate

I have an entity Note and component FavoriteNote, here is the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE NOTE (
  ID INTEGER,
  TITLE VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET UTF8,
  CONTENT BLOB SUB_TYPE 1 CHARACTER SET UTF8,
  TYPE_NO INTEGER,
  DEL SMALLINT,
  CREATE_DATE TIMESTAMP,
  UPDATE_DATE TIMESTAMP);

CREATE TABLE FAVORITE (
  NOTE_NO INTEGER NOT NULL,
  DROP_IN_DATE DATE);
```

and java code is :

```
public class FavoriteNote {
    private Note note;
    private Date dropInDate;

    public Note getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public void setNote(Note note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

    public Date getDropInDate() {
        return dropInDate;
    }

    public void setDropInDate(Date dropInDate) {
        this.dropInDate = dropInDate;
    }
}

public class Note implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8363339156398741610L;
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String content;
    private String typeName;
    private int del;
    private int show;
    private NoteType noteType;
    private BeanState beanState;
    private Date createDate;
    private Date updateDate;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }


    public int getDel() {
        return del;
    }

    public void setDel(int del) {
        this.del = del;
    }

    public int getShow() {
        return show;
    }

    public void setShow(int show) {
        this.show = show;
    }

    public NoteType getNoteType() {
        return noteType;
    }

    public void setNoteType(NoteType noteType) {
        this.noteType = noteType;
    }


    public String getTypeName() {
        return typeName;
    }

    public void setTypeName(String typeName) {
        this.typeName = typeName;
    }


    public BeanState getState() {
        return beanState;
    }

    public void setState(BeanState beanState) {
        this.beanState = beanState;
    }

    @Override
    public String getClassName() {
        return "Note";
    }

    public Date getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }

    public void setCreateDate(Date createDate) {
        this.createDate = createDate;
    }

    public Date getUpdateDate() {
        return updateDate;
    }

    public void setUpdateDate(Date updateDate) {
        this.updateDate = updateDate;
    }
}
```

the problem is FavoriateNote is not part of Note, they just have a one to one association. How to configurate the association in order to make retrieving all FavoriteNotes possible? It'd better done in xml manner.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question. You don't need to do anything more to be able to retrieve all the favorite notes. What do you want to do? Make the association bidirectional?

Comment: I don't know what configurations are needed to retrieve all the favorite notes. As I know, there is no seperate configuration xml for components ,it's just configurated within an entity hbm xml, but in my case the entity doesn't own favorites, favorate components own note entity which means you can't define <compoent> or <set> in Note.hbm.xml, so I don't know where and how to make it.

Comment: You haven't shown your mapping. You've just said you has a one-to-one association. So I assumed FavoiteNote was mapped as an entity. And this iw what you want if you plan to be able to search for FavoriteNotes. If you design it as a component, it won't have its own existence. It'll be part of a Note. Just read the hibernate documentation, and see how to map a one-to-one association between entities. And I would advise using annotations. XML config is much harder.

Comment: `session.createCriteria(FavoriteNote.class).list()` gives you all favorites no?

Comment: Note.hbm.xml can be found at https://github.com/fxbird/notebook/blob/master/src/dao/hbn/Note.hbm.xml , Entity must have primary key, but apparently in my case FavoriteNotes doesn't have to own pk, so I don't think it should be considered as an entity. Any other suggestion?

Comment: If FavorateNotes was entity, what its primary key was?